# Which sources should I believe regarding CV-8 Hornet?

Tags: world-war-two, historiography

According to wikipedia's [The Battle of Midway](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Battle_of_Midway), the Naval Carrier CV-8 "Hornet" participated in the Pacific theatre in 1942. Where could I find more confirmation on the Hornet?

[image: Hornet CV-8 under attack]

Comment: I thought the USS Hornet (CV-8) was sunk and then a new Aircraft Carrier was renamed to USS Hornet (CV-12)?

Comment: The Hornet CV-8 had a crew complement of 2,919 people. Quite an achievement to erase which ship they served on. Also the Hornet CV-8 is not listed in the aforementioned Wikipedia category.

Comment: Voting to close. I'm afraid your question isn't exactly clear, and from the parts I understand it seems to be more about conspiracy theories than factual history (therefore, off topic for this site).

Comment: My question is "Was Hornet CV-8 really exist?" it is about history of World War II.

Comment: As this question stands, it should be closed; it is tied to conspiracy theories.  If you remove the more fantastic elements and focus the question on the history of CV-8, the question is acceptable.

Comment: The voices in my head told me to close this question. Yannis, stop broadcasting!

Comment: Voting to reopen this. Although the latest edit asks a completely different question from the original version, the edit was done by the original poster, which makes it acceptable.

Comment: With the last edit it's a question for resources, which is trivially answered by pointing to Wikipedia. So I'm afraid I still think it should be closed.

Comment: This is acceptable as a historiography question. I recast it as such, and joined the vote to reopen.

Comment: Video source (emphasis mine): "Battle 360 - Vengeance At Midway from **History Channel**". So at best, the "History" Channel simply skipped info to fit the video format; at worse, the "History" Channel is ... [bad](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lTf9O-CHJFQ), really [*really* bad](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fUHk9FLZMf4).

Comment: Actually I should now answer **every** question with *"It was Ancient Aliens"*. Fall of Rome? *Ancient Aliens*. Battle of Gettysburg? *Ancient Aliens*.

Comment: As question now stands, it's a question about what sources are acceptable and reliable. That's not a question that is limited or even specific for the USS Hornet.

Comment: Not one word? http://youtu.be/ttzczopr1LY?t=3m02s http://youtu.be/ttzczopr1LY?t=4m25s http://youtu.be/ttzczopr1LY?t=5m25s

Comment: @LennartRegebro:Thanks for finishing the repair "job" that I started.

Answer (score 6):

[Here](http://www.navsource.org/archives/02/08.htm) is an internet archive of photographs and film footage of the USS Hornet (CV-8), during her construction and operation. There is a sizable section on her participation in the Battle of Midway, with both stills and motion pictures (can't really call it video... it was shot on film.)

So, no, there is no conspiracy to cover up the USS Hornet's (CV-8) existence or her participation in the battle of Midway.

Comment: Could you tell me, why there is every Discovery's films tells that there was Yorktown instead of Hornet, and no Hornet at all...

Comment: @polarbearonthewhitesnow - Probably because they slapped together a documentary on the cheap, and couldn't afford fact checkers to correct rudimentary mistakes. Never ascribe to malice that which can be explained by incompetence.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ttzczopr1LY - here e.g. not the same what I have read in the wikipedia's article.

Comment: Is there must be an official video from the board of carrier during the Midway's Battle? Or at least photoshoot?

Comment: @polarbearonthewhitesnow - Battlefield 360 is pretty terrible. Try John Ford's "Battle of Midway" - it's been remastered recently.

Comment: The mistake of course, is assuming the Discovery Channel [has any viable content](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/NetworkDecay) other than *Shark Week*.

Comment: @LateralFractal And Mythbusters.

Comment: @RISwampYankee - The '76 dramatic film wasn't too bad either. (Beats the crap out of the Michael Bay Pearl Harbor film)